# Problema no auth customizado laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando configurar uma tabela personalizada para o auth no laravel 7.x. O login funciona normalmente, porém o registro de um novo usuário retorna o erro: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rh.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `cpf` = 000000)". A tabela "users" foi substituida por "usuários" e fiz as alterações no auth.php, alterei o $table na model e a função create dentro do controller, mas o erro ainda  é exibido.

Minha model está assim:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Usuarios extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = "usuarios";
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome',
        'cpf',
        'email',
        'telefone',
        'endereco',
        'numero',
        'complemento',
        'bairro',
        'cidade',
        'estado',
        'cep',
        'celular',
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Meu controller está assim:

```
middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'nome' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'cpf' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'telefone' => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'endereco' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'numero' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'complemento' => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'bairro' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'cidade' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'estado' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'cep' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'celular' => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\Usuarios
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Usuarios::create([
            'nome' => $data['nome'],
            'cpf' => $data['cpf'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'telefone' => $data['telefone'],
            'endereco' => $data['endereco'],
            'numero' => $data['numero'],
            'complemento' => $data['complemento'],
            'bairro' => $data['bairro'],
            'cidade' => $data['cidade'],
            'estado' => $data['estado'],
            'cep' => $data['cep'],
            'celular' => $data['celular'],
            'senha' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

E meu auth.php está assim:

```
 [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'usuarios',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'usuarios',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'usuarios',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'usuarios' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Usuarios::class
        ],

        /* 'usuarios' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'usuarios',
        ], */
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'usuarios' => [
            'provider' => 'usuarios',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: o método `Create` tem um erro no final com o campo senha que não existe? pelo menos no model não. Em qual momento dá esse erro da tabela `users`?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem dois erros no seu código um deles no método de validação onde tu colocou a tabela `users` que na verdade é `usuarios` na validação `unique` de `cpf` e `email` exemplo como deveria ser:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'nome' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'cpf' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:usuarios'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:usuarios'],
        'telefone' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'endereco' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'numero' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'complemento' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'bairro' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'cidade' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'estado' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'cep' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'celular' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

e no `Create` porque o campo não é `senha` e sim `password` como descrito no seu modelo `Usuarios`:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return Usuarios::create([
        'nome' => $data['nome'],
        'cpf' => $data['cpf'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'telefone' => $data['telefone'],
        'endereco' => $data['endereco'],
        'numero' => $data['numero'],
        'complemento' => $data['complemento'],
        'bairro' => $data['bairro'],
        'cidade' => $data['cidade'],
        'estado' => $data['estado'],
        'cep' => $data['cep'],
        'celular' => $data['celular'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

são erros de digitação.

Comment: Funcionou, agora ta 100%, eu nem tinha reparado nesses detalhes, valeu mesmo